# Django - if value add 3 and update to IntegerField

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm making a score app. Users can guess the next game result / winner. Now if the user guess the winning team, I want the userscore (points) to add 3 to the DB field. For this I got following Models:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    points = models.IntegerField(null=True, default=0)


class Tipp(models.Model):
    user        = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    result_hometeam1 = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    result_guestteam1 = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)


class Game(models.Model):
    hometeam1 = models.ForeignKey(Teams, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="hometeam1", blank=True, null=True)
    result_hometeam1 = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    guestteam1 = models.ForeignKey(Teams, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="guestteam1", blank=True, null=True)
    result_guestteam1 = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

E.G the user guess results: hometeam1 vs. guestteam1 10:20 and the final result is 15:20 the user guess the right winner and the points row should get 3 points to the current value.

I tried to do in the template but thats not a good choice:

```
{% if game.get.result_hometeam1 <= user_tipp.get.result_hometeam1 %}
        {{ users.get.points|add:3 }}
{% endif %}
```

I havn't found a method to do this if statement in the views.py. I searched for Query Expressions in the Docs but I couldn't found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the backend in your views.py file. For example:

```
def check_results(request):
    <Your if statement>
      customer = Customer.objects.filter(name=request.user)
      customer.points += 1
      customer.save()
```

It would be also easier to help you more if you shared your views.py file.